# Inter-class use of variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I'm trying to create a class with some instance variables that can be linked to and manipulated by a separate class. Here's my code:

```
class Product
  attr_accessor :name, :quantity
  def initialize(name, quantity)
    @name = name
    @quantity = quantity
  end
end

class Production
  def initialize(factory)
    @factory = factory
  end
  def create
    "#{@name}: #{@factory}"
  end
end
```

Basically, I'd like to be able to use attributes from an instance of the Product class in the Production class. So if A = Product.new('widget', 100), I want to be able to call A.name as a variable in an instance of Production. To test this I have:

```
a = Product.new('widget', 100)
b = Production.new('Building 1')
puts b.create('Building 1')
```

However, it's returning the following:

```
: Building 1
```

instead of

```
widget: Building 1
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong? Ultimately I'd also like to add, subtract, etc. from the quantity. I'm hoping that if I figure out how to link the name property I can do the same for the quantity pretty easily.

Comment: Please check your code. Why does `create` have no parameter, but is called with one? How should instances of `Product` and `Production` be linked? Currently, they have no association at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you want to produce a `Product` during a `Production`, so the `Production` must know about the `Product`. You can for example pass the product as an argument to `create`:

```
class Production
  def initialize(factory)
    @factory = factory
  end

  def create(product)
    "#{product.name}: #{@factory}"
  end
end

product = Product.new('Thingy', 123)
production = Production.new('ACME')
puts production.create(product)
#=> "Thingy: ACME"
```

or you could store it in an instance variable if you need it across the entire `Production` class:

```
class Production
  def initialize(factory, product)
    @factory = factory
    @product = product
  end

  def create
    "#{@product.name}: #{@factory}"
  end
end

product = Product.new('Thingy', 123)
production = Production.new('ACME', product)
puts production.create
#=> "Thingy: ACME"
```

Comment: This edit may work, but not for my purposes.  I was given a set of tests, and production can only take one argument.  Is there a way to structure the classes so that the variables from the first class can be accessed by the second, without changing the test requirements?

Comment: No, they're instance variables so they are only accessible inside a single instance. That's the only thing that makes sense because how should Ruby know which Product you mean if you have multiple? You need to pass the product to the production class somehow, there's no getting around that.